# How to make an item print three times then start a new row while keeping the name of user inputs

Tags: python

[image]

Currently using Python 3.5.1

I've been trying to work on this code for hours. I need this for homework any tips or leads for anything im struggling tired and frustrated.

All I got was

- HB
- HB
- HB
- HB

What I need is HB HB HB

HB HB HB HB

This is my first programming class so all we really worked on was If, else, print, input, while, if i in range, and other basic python statements.

Comment: It's really difficult to discern what is going on in that screenshot you posted.  Instead, you should post the code that you are using.  The behavior you are seeing and what is unexpected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two aspects here:

1. printing 'HB' on the same line multiple times
2. adding a new line every 3 times HB prints

To get HB to print on the same line, you add additional arguments to the print function like this:

print('HB', end='')

The default end is a new line, so this changes it to print on one line.

To have a new line added after every 3 prints, the easiest way is to use the modulus operator (%) so that you add a new line when division by 3 has a 0 remainder.

One way to achieve this for your example would be this:

```
num_times = int(input('How many times should display HB '))

for i in range(num_times):
    print('HB ', end='')
    if (i + 1)%3 == 0:
        print('\n')
```

Comment: Thank you im learning im just trying to understand it more since I never learned this in class

Answer (score 0):

For python 3, use argument  `end=''` (empty string) in the print function to prevent changing lines (see documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)